# How to enable checkboxes in markdown preview for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I'm trying to enable markdown checkboxes in vscode markdown preview but am not having any luck. I've tried every combination of the following extensions with no luck:

- Markdown Preview Enhanced
- Markdown All in One
- Markdown Preview Github Styling
- Markdown Checkbox
- Markdown Checkboxes

Does anyone have a configuration of extensions where this is working for you?

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same issue, and it looks like VSCode markdown does [not](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53993) support checkboxes and you need to install an extension.

Comment: 2023, still not supported. VSCodium v1.79.2

Comment: 2024, still not supported. VS Code Insiders 1.88

Answer (score 12):

Checkboxes work in VS Code using the [Markdown All In One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) extension. The trick is that the checkboxes also have to be part of a list.

❌ This doesn't work:

```markdown
[ ] Unchecked
[ ] Checked
```

✅ This works:

```markdown
- [ ] Unchecked
- [x] Checked
```

[image]

---

The "task list" syntax was first introduced to GitHub flavored Markdown back in January 2013.

- [GitHub flavored Markdown - Task list items (extension)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#task-list-items-extension-)
- [GitLab flavored Markdown - Task lists](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#task-lists)

Comment: This works showing the checkboxes in their current state, but can't click them. Any way of doing that?

Comment: note I thought this wasn't working for me, but didn't notice that unchecked boxes need a space between the two brackets.

Comment: @NeithanMax  Alt + C should do it.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one#keyboard-shortcuts-1

Comment: This extension makes checkboxes work without list: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.markdown-extended&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: @VanitySlug-codidact.com the "Markdown Extended" extension makes checkboxes toggleable, but it does not alter the underlying Markdown text content. I think that is misleading, and pointless. This answer should be accepted as the solution.

Answer (score 7):

As of January, 2022 this is working for me in a markdown preview:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked> some checked text  
<input type="checkbox"> some unchecked text
```

[image: markdown checkbox demo]

**NOTE** This works in a published vscode extension markdown file (in the Marketplace):

[image: marketplace checkbox markdown demo]

But I am still investigating getting it to work in github - any ideas?  `input` elements do not appear to be in the prohibited list so it "should" work somehow.

But see https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/blob/main/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb `input` elements are not in the allowed list in the sanitizer file.

Comment: You are using HTML tags instead of markdown text like `- [x]` or `- [ ]`

Comment: does this keep checkboxes that you've checked from the preview checked?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the combination I use to replicate Github's styling for my READMEs

**Make sure you reload VSCode after installing!**

```
Name: GitHub Markdown Preview
Id: bierner.github-markdown-preview
Description: Changes VS Code's built-in markdown preview to match GitHub
Version: 0.2.0
Publisher: Matt Bierner
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.github-markdown-preview
```

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that for the extension "Markdown Checkbox" by Matt Bierner to work properly in checking boxes in preview, you have to either disable or uninstall "Markdown All in One". All in One seems to be prioritized in the rendering of the checkboxes over the first extension in which they can actually be checked

Could be great to have some kind of fork in between both extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I lost all day and no found the solution. I solved with a simple manera in vb.net ...

two instruction and work...

nCheckBox.Checked = False

nCheckBox.Checked = True

Answer (score 0):

The Git Markdown syntax doesn't really work in the example:

```py
- [x] Check them all
```

I found an alternative and use emoji, like  ✅ ⬜

Answer (score -1):

Found this here:

> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#task-lists

You can do Markdown checkboxes like this in VS Code text boxes (and I'm sure .md files too) in list items:

```markdown
- [ ]  **Bug 1** Totally Inconceivable!  
- [x]  **Bug 2** You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.
```

To "check" the checkbox, replace the space in the square brackets with an `x`.

Comment: Those don't work in vscode's markdown preview, which is what the question is about.